# Looking for title of youth book, possibly SBS, ocean going salvage tug, North Atlantic, Argentine

Tags: identification-request

Looking for the name of a book I read as a kid (45-55 years ago).  Premise was an Argentine ocean going salvage tug in the Atlantic, finds a drifting unmanned freighter loaded with scrap metal.  Some of the scrap was in the form of old steam locomotives.  One of the locos had broken its lashings and was hanging partially over one side, ship had a bit of a list.  Tug is low on coal and they have to try to salvage coal from the drifter, take it in tow and get it back to BA.  I don't recall if the drifter was why they were out on the water or if finding it was serendipitous.  I think they may have been racing a competitor to another salvage and lost the race, not sure.

This may have been a Scholastic Book Service title but not certain of that.  I received the book a couple of years before I was really old enough to enjoy it but vaguely recall reading it and liking it in early 70's say 7th or 8th grade.  Cover art was a drawing or painting, color, showing the drifting freighter with the locomotive partly hanging over one side.  The sea grey and blue with tall waves and whitecaps.  In my minds eye the painting portrays the ship bows to the left so the loco would have been port side.
The book may have been translated into English from the writers native language, for some reason that rings a vague bell

Have tried storyline searches and have tried looking for comprehensive SBS title lists to no avail.